# Add ACF in table wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, field, advanced-custom-fields

I have a text field with ACF.

On one page where I have a simple table, I want to import that ACF text into one field in the table. But not sure how to add?

Comment: You can do it like this: <?php the_field('field_name'); ?>. But please add more details like the name of your ACF field and the HTML code of your table

Comment: The name of the field : sqr

Html table simple with tr and td, or I can create table with table in Avada theme builder if that is better. I was try with the code you have sent, but in hrml, when I save, it disapeared.

Comment: So you want to add the field data in the editor not in a theme file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To add it in the editor:**

You can add field data with a simple shortcode. Try to add the following shortcode in your table:

```
[acf field="sqr" post_id="123"]
```

You need to change the number in `post_id="123"` with the actual ID from your page.

Look in the URL field of your browser, there you should find the ID like here:

```
example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=123&action=edit
```

Here's more about that: [Shortcode](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/shortcode/)

**To add it in the product template**

Add this code to your template:

```
<?php $sqr = get_field('sqr'); ?>
```

After that you can use the following code in your table:

```
<?php echo $sqr; ?>
```

Or just use the following code (without extra variable):

```
<?php the_field('sqr'); ?>
```

Here's more about that: [get_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)

Comment: I want that to use on the product page template

Comment: I've changed my answer

Comment: @alorange please make an extra question for that. You can link it here so I will check. And please add some code samples and an description what you want to achieve

Comment: Okay, answered it there. Please delete the comments here for a cleaner/better experience on the site. I will do the same. And if you don't mind, you can upvote my answer if it helps you ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the value of an ACF field, you can use the function get_field

```
$valueOfMyAcfTextField = get_field(‘name_of_the_field’);
```

Then you can simply echo it where you want in your template:

```
<?php echo $valueOfMyAcfTextField; ?>
```

or directly like that:

```
<?php echo get_field(‘name_of_the_field’); ?>
```

Beware the name of the field is the key of the field not the title.

Hope it helps